# Remove line under custom navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've been trying to create a Navigation Bar with a background image but have been running into a lot of trouble.

[image]

Two problems that I can't solve:

1) The pink line under the image

2) The back button should be moved up a little

This is the code I use to place the image:

```
class CustomNavController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let img = UIImage(named: "topbar60.png"){
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
        }
    }
}
```

Original bar image:
[image]

If anyone is feeling really charitable you can just plug the image and Navigation Controller subclass into an empty project to try to solve this.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: After hours (days?) spent trying to get the navbar to look just how I want, I decided to hide the default bar and create a `UIView` and style it the way I want. Saved me hours of frustration

Comment: @toddg thanks that's what I started doing but ran into another problem. Can't place a uiview inside a uitableviewcontroller but outside the table view so that it's fixed at the top and not scrolling with the uitableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, You are getting the pink underline because the image's height is 60 while the navigation bar's height is 64. If you change your image's height to 64, the pink line will disappear.

As for your second question, it is a bit more complicated. Your best bet would be probably to create a custom `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: Glad to be of help